# d3 indented tree close other nodes with child and open only specific node

Tags: javascript, php, d3.js, tree

Hi i will use this jsfiddle as reference  http://jsfiddle.net/Ge58Q/16/

```
 function expandSingle(d) {
  if (d._children) {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
 }
}
```

as you can see i have a tree that has a multiple branch. What i want to do is  onload i only want the NODE LIGHTNING has the child that open and that is the NODE TURBO. the NODES CUTE AND NODE TOXIC  i want their child to be hidden.  Is this possible to open only the specific node that i want?????????

i think it has something to do with the above code

Comment: something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Ge58Q/17/

Comment: dynamically means that it will expand the path to the node with specific value? e.g. you input `turbo` and it will expand the path to node with `turbo` value?

Comment: exactly like that but from root up to the target node. If the tree has many branches their branches need to be close. i only want to show the path from the root up to the target node without opening the child of the other nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to expand the path from root to node with specific name, you could use some algorithm to get the path, e.g. depth-first with stack where you store the path. Here is the sample of function which encapsulates recursive function and returns the array with indexes of `children` positions from root to node:

```
function getPathToNode(val, rootNode) {
    var stack = [];
    var nodeFound = false;
    function getPathRec(node) {
        if (nodeFound) {
            return;
        }
        if (node._children || node.children) {
            var nodeChildren = node.children ? node.children : node._children;
            for (var i=0; i<nodeChildren.length; i++) {
                if (!nodeFound) {
                    stack.push(i);
                    getPathRec(nodeChildren[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        if  (node.name == val && !nodeFound) {
            nodeFound = true;
            return;
        } else if (!nodeFound) {
            stack.pop();
        }
    }
    getPathRec(rootNode);
    return stack;
}
```

Then you could expand the nodes on the path:

```
function expandToNode(val) {
    path = getPathToNode(val, flare);
    currentNode = flare;
    for (var i=0; i<path.length - 1; i++) {
        currentNode = currentNode.children[path[i]];
        expandSingle(currentNode);
    }
}
```

So simply call the function `expandToNodes(val)` with name of the node as `val parameter`:

```
expandToNode('turbo');
```

This is the working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ge58Q/18/

**Limitations:** if there were multiple nodes with exact name, it expands only the first found node. If you would like to expand all the routes, you could traverse whole root and return all of the paths. I tested the code only with your tree data so there could be some bugs.

Comment: Hi @knives22 I am glad that my answer was helpful!